# maven downloading jar even I have deleted its entry from pom.xml

Tags: maven, jar, pom.xml

I have commented out the entry of "powermock-api-easymock" in pom.xml but every time i run mvn compile, This jar gets created in my. m2/repository folder.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-easymock</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I have manually deleted it, still it is getting created.

Comment: have you tried a `maven clean` before rebuilding?

Comment: yes, I have tried it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maven requests the artifact because it is either a (transitive) dependency of your project or of one of your plugins.

If you run

```
mvn dependency:list
```

you can see whether it (still) appears in your transitive dependencies. If so, you can use `mvn dependency:tree` to find the dependency of yours that pulls it in.

Otherwise it is probably a dependency of your plugins.

Please allow me the question: What is the harm in having this file in your local repository?

Comment: Meier, This is working fine on my local machine but failing on Jenkins.
I am getting below error in log console

Could not resolve dependencies for project <project name> Failed to collect dependencies at org.powermock:powermock-api-easymock:jar:1.6.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.powermock:powermock-api-easymock:jar:1.6.1: Could not transfer artifact org.powermock:powermock-api-easymock:pom:1.6.1 from/to proj-nexus.Remote host closed connection during handshake: SSL peer shut down incorrectly.

So I thought to remove it from Pom as it was nowhere used. I am using powerMock

Comment: Meier, I tried with mvn dependency:list and mvn dependency:tree command.
There was no "powermock-api-easymock" present in output. What does it mean ?

Comment: Your Jenkins seems to have network issues or errors in the settings.xml. I would try to solve these issues first. Powermock might be a dependency of a plugin.  But if you solve your Jenkins issues you probably do not need to care.